# Need an example: #define may be removed by the preprocessor before the source code gets to a compiler

Tags: c++

I am reading effective c++. When it comes to Item 2 (prefer const, enum, and inline to #define), Scott says: #define is often treated as if it's not part of the language, and it may be removed by the preprocessor before the source code gets to a complier.

Can anyone show me an example about this ? thanks.

Comment: What's up with the example given? (Ref: http://210.212.249.121/ebook/cse/013/EffectiveC++/EC/EI1_FR.HTM )

Comment: An Example? Every example of `#define` does that. All pre-processor directives are always evaluated before compilation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a somewhat fuzzy statement, but formally the preprocessor is a separate phase of compilation, and back in the olden days the preprocessor was a separate program that did its thing before the compiler got to see the code. Most compilers have an option to only do the preprocessing, which is sometimes helpful for figuring out where some code has gone astray. But under the "as if" rule, the compiler doesn't **have to** do preprocessing in a separate phase; it just has to produce the same result as if it had done that.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very simple example:

```
#define MAX_COUNT 256
```

The preprocessor will replace every occurrence of `MAX_COUNT` in the relevant scope with `256` before passing it off to the compiler.

In a broad sense you can think of it as macroing:

```
#define FOO(a,b) a*b+a+b
```

will replace `FOO(a,b)` with `a*b+a+b`

For more reading on the preprocessor, you can also consult this [page](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/cpreprocessor.html).